# Trying to compare two attributes of different classes in python, getting error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Sheep"

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where sheep roam around a plain and eat grass while wolves chase after the sheep. Everything worked fine until I got to the wolf AI trying to compare the sheep's location against their own. Here's my code for that is causing the error:

```
    def trackSheep(self, sheepList):
    sheepFound = 0#0 = false, 1 = true
    for s in sheepList:
        if sheepFound == 0:
            if sheepList[s].x == self.x and sheepList[s].y == self.y:
                self.energy = self.energy + sheepList[s].energy
            else:
                distanceToSheep = sheepList[s].x + sheepList[s].y
                if distanceToSheep < SHEEP_DETECTED_RANGE:
                    return [(sheepList[s].x,  sheepList[s].y)]
                    sheepFound = 1
        else:
            break
    if sheepFound == 0:
        return False
```

The error is on line 5 where I'm trying to see if the sheep's position is equal to that of the wolves. That is when it returns the error in the title. SheepList is an array consisting of multiple Sheep class objects. I'm calling the code in this function:

```
    def update(self, sheepList):#all logic for the wolves
    if self.isAlive():
        nearbySheep = self.trackSheep(sheepList)
        if not nearbySheep == False:
            self.huntSheep(nearbySheep)
        else:
            self.move()
    else:
        #add death behavior later
        self.color = p.Color("black")
```

which is triggered by my main function:

```
def main():
framerate = 30
p.init
clock=p.time.Clock()
screen=p.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
screen.fill((0,0,0))
p.display.set_caption("Wolf Sheep Simulation")
running = True
#testSheep = s(5,3)
#testSheep.draw(screen)
SheepList = spawnInitialSheep()
WolfList = spawnInitialWolves()
testGrass = Grass(3,5)
spawnGrass()

while running:
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            running = False
    print(grassList)
    print(SheepList)
    for s in SheepList:
        s.update(grassList)
    for w in WolfList:
        w.update(SheepList)

    testGrass.draw(screen)
    #updte things
    #draw things
    for grassRow in grassList:
        for grassSquare in grassRow:
            grassSquare.update()
            grassSquare.draw(screen)
    for i in range (len(SheepList)):
        SheepList[i].draw(screen)
    for i in range (len(WolfList)):
        WolfList[i].draw(screen)
    p.display.flip()
    clock.tick(framerate)

p.quit()
```

main()

I'm assuming it's a simple formatting error, anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is baa-a-a-a-ad:

```
for s in sheepList:
    if sheepFound == 0:
        if sheepList[s].x == self.x and sheepList[s].y == self.y:    
        #  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        # s is already a sheep object
            self.energy = self.energy + sheepList[s].energy
```

Instead, you can simply use the sheep object, without going back to the sheepList over and over again:

```
for sheep in sheepList:
    if sheepFound == 0:
        if sheep.x == self.x and sheep.y == self.y:    
            self.energy = self.energy + sheep.energy
```

Similarly, in your main function instead of this:

```
for i in range (len(SheepList)):
    SheepList[i].draw(screen)
for i in range (len(WolfList)):
    WolfList[i].draw(screen)
```

...it would be more conventional to simply write:

```
for sheep in SheepList:
    sheep.draw(screen)
for wolf in WolfList:
    wolf.draw(screen)
```

Or, simplifying further:

```
for animal in itertools.chain(SheepList, WolfList):
    # Watch out for wolf in sheep's clothing.
    animal.draw(screen)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm just getting another completely different error that crashes my program shortly after it starts every time, but atleast it works now.

Comment: Certainly. If you can’t solve the next problem, you could post another question. Often, the process of narrowing things down to formulate a question leads to you finding a solution.  Good luck!

Comment: Actually, any chance of you being able to help with the error I'm currently getting?

EDIT: Nvm i'll just make a new question I can't format the code correctly here.